# How to display images from Advanced Custom Fields relationship fields in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Main Case Studies Page, where I would like to show the images from each of the case studies post type pages in a list. I have the following code:

```
    <div class="CaseStudyOverview" id="CaseStudyOverview">
<div class="CaseStudyOverview-Contents">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="CaseStudyPic-left">
            <div class="CaseStudyRightButton">
                <?php 

                    $photo = get_field('casestudy_image');
                    $pic   = get_field('casestudy_platform_image');

                ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $photo['url']; ?>" />

                    <a href="<?php the_field('case_studies_go_to_button_link'); ?>" class="make-Button--link"><?php the_field('case_studies_go_to_button');  ?></a>
            </div><!-- end of CaseStudyRightButton -->
            <div class="CaseStudyLeftPic">
                <img src="<?php echo $pic['url'];  ?>" />
            </div><!-- end of left-pic -->
        </div><!-- end of content-left -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- end of CaseStudyOverview-Contents -->
```

Is there anything missing?

Comment: I don't understand what all of these empty tags are for...`<img src="<?php  ?>">`. Also, what's happening currently?

Comment: I didn't put the field in for that one yet, the top portion which is the div CaseStudyPic-left the one I put in the fields for. Currently nothing is showing in that one

Comment: If you are using relationship then you have to get page or post id into the loop and you have to pass that id to get image url using wp_get_attachment_url() and pass that url into <img src="">.